# How to extract columns before and after a string ocurrence

Tags: awk, files, grep, string, search

I have a text file. That looks like:

```
www.ac.com has address 6.1.1.146 www.ac.com is an alias for ac.com. www.ac.com is an alias for ac.com.
www.ba.net is an alias for www-bn.gs.ba.com. www-bn.gs.ba.com has address 11.28.11.4 ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I want to extract the column before and after `has address` and separate them by comma. So I want to get:

```
www.ac.com,6.1.1.146
www-bn.gs.ba.com,11.28.11.4
```

How to do this? I have tried `awk '{print $1,$4}' myfile > newfile` but it could not work well as it is not always the case what I want is in columns 1 and 4. The columns of interests can vary but always separated by `has address`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `grep` and `sed`:

```
grep -o '[^ ]* has address [^ ]*' | sed 's/ has address /,/'
```

I like this one, because it's so easy.

---

**Explanation**:

`grep` will output only the matching (`-o`) part of each line that it finds the following pattern:

- any character that is not a space (`[^ ]*`) folllowed by `has address` followed by again any character that is not a space (`[^ ]*`).

`sed` will simply replace `has address` with `,`

Comment: Clever! +1. Maybe a short explanation would be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

In `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(.* |^)([^ ]*) has address ([^ ]*)( .*|$)/\2,\3/' myfile > newfile
```

## Explanation

- `sed -r 's/foo/bar/' myfile > newfile`: use `sed` with "extended regular expressions" (`-r`), so we don't need to escape capturing groups `()` below. Replace occurrences of `foo` with `bar`. Read from `myfile` and write to `newfile`.
- `(.* |^)([^ ]*) has address ([^ ]*)( .*|$)`: look for the string `has address`, preceded and followed by a space. Before and after this should be a string that doesn't include spaces, which we should capture in a group `([^ ]*)`. Before the leading word should be either a space (preceded by whatever, `.*`) or the beginning of the line, i.e. `(.* |^)`. After the following word should be either a space (followed by whatever, `.*`), or the end of the line, i.e. `( .*|$)`.
- `\2,\3`: the expression above captures the whole line, so replace it with the second and third capturing groups, i.e. the word before and after `has address`.

Comment: Nice one. I was looking for this one too but couldn't make it because of sed's greedyness. Now I know why, this is so unreadable ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nE '/(\S+) has address (\S+)/ and say "$1,$2"' x
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=, '
  {
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
      j=i+1;
      if ($i=="has" && $j=="address") {
        domain=i-1;
        ip=i+2;
        print $domain,$ip;
        break;
      }
    }
  }'
```

Loops through the fields, and if it finds "has" and the next field is "address", it will print the fields before and after that with `,` as output field separator.